# Printf puts a percent sign after everything it prints

Tags: printf, zsh, text-formatting, konsole

Whenever I use `printf` in the shell whether it is within `awk`, a standalone application, or in C/C++ it prints a "%" after everything. For instance, when I type `printf "hi"` I get this as an output `hi%`. I am on Arch Linux using zsh as a shell and konsole as a terminal emulator. The font I use is MesloLGS NF.

Image:

[image: My Terminal]

Comment: because you get the prompt after your string that doesn't end on a newline?

Comment: @RussellHynes : This comes from the way you have configured `PS1`, as you can verify when you do a `echo $PS1`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is `zsh`'s way of telling you that the preceding command outputted a partial line and the shell terminated that line to give you a prompt on a new line.

You can disable this behavior by typing `PROMPT_EOL_MARK=''` into the command prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me recognize my issue, but putting PROMPT_EOL_MARK='' did nothing.

Comment: Nevermind, I just can't pass it like PROMPT_EOL_MARK='' {program_name}

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: But from the [docs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshparam), I would conclude that `PROMPT_EOL_MARK` affects only so-called _partial lines_. This is discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/why-zsh-ends-a-line-with-a-highlighted-percent-symbol#167600).

Comment: @user1934428 Correct. If you change the command to output a full line, the `%` will disappear.

Comment: you may add `export PROMPT_EOL_MARK=''` to you ~/.zshrc